# Watson STT using java-sdk:3.5.1

Tags: java, android, ibm-watson

I am unable to do a Watson Speech to text using java-sdk:3.5.1 as all the sample examples I referred are using an older version of java- 2.10.0. https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/android-sdk

Can anyone help me find a sample using java-sdk 3.5.1? Thanks

[image]

Comment: Thanks anyways. I solved the issue though it took me one whole day.

Comment: What was the solution? Could you please post it as an answer to your question.